# How can I use an angularjs directive to dynamically add attributes for form validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a directive that I'm using to validate form fields. I want to dynamically add the validation with the directive. Here's what my directive looks like:

```
app.directive('validatedInput', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var constraints = {
                'ng-maxlength' : 10,
                'data-required': ''
            }

            angular.forEach(constraints, function(value, key) {
                element.attr(key, value);
            }

            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my markup:

```
<input type='number' name='fieldName' ng-model='data.test' validated-input></input>
```

So basically what I want is for the directive to add `ng-maxlength=10` and `data-required=''` to my input element so that the validation can work (this is a trivial case; in the future I plan on getting the constraints object from the back-end using a service). The problem is, the directive seems to add the attributes to the DOM, but the validation doesn't work. In other words, if I inspect the HTML using my browser's dev tools, the markup looks correct, but the functionality isn't there. Any thoughts?

Much appreciated

Comment: Seems like the `$compile` service is relevant: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: I tried to add `$compile(element)(scope);` right after the forEach loop and I get a console message stating `$compile is not a function`

Comment: `$compile is not a function` is likely because you didn't inject `$compile` in directive

Comment: I apologize, I did indeed inject $compile into the directive. Same error

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I've editted the above code to reflect a call to $compile. This code gives me the `$compile is not a function` error

Answer (score 0):

I only have a bit of Angular experience (~6 weeks), but everything I've seen in regards to Directives to do DOM in Angular is clunky as fu...nky chicken...

I'm doing this currently with jQuery (which has zero chicken funk DOM manip. wise) to do a $compile after dynamically adding ng-attributes (in this case so the INPUT name is calculated for the crappy bootstrap/angular datepicker control I'm using currently):

```
//# Hook the .calendars object via the required Angular attributes
$('I.icon-calendar').each(function (i, obj) {
    var $s, $p = $(this).parent();

    //# Set the ng-click of the .parent button
    $p.attr('ng-click', "calendars.open($event)");

    //# Setup the calendar INPUT
    $s = $p.siblings('INPUT[datepicker-options]');
    $s.attr('is-open', "calendars.isOpen['" + $s.attr('name') + "']");

    //# Re-$compile the DOM elements so all of the above added Angular attributes are processed
    $compile($s.get(0))($scope);
    $compile($p.get(0))($scope);
});
```

$compile needs to be "injected" (I hate that term, why can't we just say "passed"?) into the controller, a'la:

```
myApp.factory("Tools", function ($http, $q, $timeout, $compile) {...}
```

The only issue I've had thus far is some controls/plugins/etc. add DOM elements on $compile, so currently I'm wrestling the dragon of multiple datepicker UL.dropdown-menu's being added to the DOM, to which I have no answer (but I did find this question on the way, so there's that).